# sending data from PLC to a web server http://localhost:8080

Tags: node.js, django, tcp, webserver, plc

I have a Programmable Logic Controller (PLC) which can work on ethernet to communicate to other devices over TCP/IP protocol.

Is it possible to receive data into the web server from external device like PLC? Also, is it possible for the web server to send data over TCP/IP protocol to other controller devices (PLC in this case)?

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that was inappropriate.  Not every question requires code.  (The link you gave is specific to debug questions).  That said, the question should be closed as needs more detail.  The answer will depend entirely on which PLC is being used.

Comment: Rajesh, I would love to help you with your questions but I need more information. What type of PLC are you going to use, what type of information are you looking to send, where are you going to send the information?

Comment: @CTGControls I have Bachmann PLC MC212 with me. I want to have a web server (say 172.0.0.1:xxxx) hosted with custom UI. This web server will be emulating a solar PV inverter connected to grid.

Now I want to give set points (ref values for power, voltage etc) from the PLC to this web server.

The web server has to take those inputs, act accordingly and send the tracked, measured data back to the PLC device. 

As far as I know, this can be done through UDP.

But I am zero % sure as to which back end programming should I use to run the server and, how to make the communication possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the LECPServer middleware, which is also developed based on Javascript, and can expose the Modbus address for reading and writing through HTTP POST.

You can use a simple code like this to display the real-time data of the PLC on the web page

```
// send
{
    "action": "plc_read_node",
    "node": "NODES.MODBUS.C0000"
}

// response
{
    "errcode": 0,
    "errmsg": "",
    "rtval": [
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ]
}
```

BTW, LECPServer is an open source project.